# read and copy buffer from kernel in CPU to kernel in FPGA with OpenCL

Tags: opencl, cpu, fpga, xilinx, vitis-ai

I'm trying to speed up Ethash algorithm on Xilinx u50 FPGA. My problem is not about FPGA, it is about pass DAG file that are generated in CPU and send it to FPGA.

first I'm using [this code](https://github.com/Ed-Yang/xilinx-ethash) in my test. I made a few changes to support Intel OpenCL driver. now if I only using CPU to run Ethash (or in this case xleth) program all process are be done. but in my case I first generate DAG file in CPU and with using 4 core it take 30 second for generating epoch number 0. after that I wanna pass DAG file (in code showing with m_dag) to a new buffer look like g_dag to send it in u50 HBMs.

I can't using only one context in this program, because I'm using 2 separated kernel files (.cl for CPU and .xclbin for FPGA) and when I try to make program and kernel it send me error 33 (CL_INVALID_DEVICE). so I make separate context (with name g_context).

now I wanna know how can I send data from m_contex to g_context? and it that ok and optimize in performance?(send me another solution if you have.)

I send my code in [this link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtS-Wbe64LCAmHyMDfHdradpH_-O?e=1cTeGD) so pls if you can, just send me code solution.